# Fusionar dos arrays de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quería saber como puedo fusionar dos `arrays` de objetos*(meter uno dentro de otro también me serviría).*

Por ejemplo:

```
array["nombre": "paco", "edad": "21"];
array2["nombre": "matias", "edad": "25"];
```

quedaría así:

```
arraydefinitivo[array, array2]
```

He probado con `push`, pero no me funciona para esto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes usar concant para unir 2 arrays

```js
var array1=[1,2,3];
var array2=[4,5,6];
array1=array1.concat(array2);
console.log(array1);
```

Otras alternativa `[].concat(array1, array2, array3);`

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];
var array3 = [7, 8, 9];
array1 = [].concat(array1, array2, array3);
console.log(array1);
```

Ahora si se quiere concatenar discriminando por alguna condicion, por ejemplo solo concatenar los numeros pares de 2 arrays

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];

array2.filter(data => data%2==0 ? array1.push(data):data);
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Me aparece "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of null"

Comment: uno de tus arrays es de tipo null

Comment: Tu respuesta es buena, aunque me parece que el fallo lo tengo por otro sitio del programa :( Aun así gracias por ayudar

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en la declaración de un array de objetos. Lo correcto sería:

```
var array1 = [
  {"nombre": "paco", "edad": "21"}
 ];

var array2 = [
  {"nombre": "matias", "edad": "25"}
 ];
```

Luego usas **concat** para unir ambos:

```
array1 = array1.concat(array2);
```

El ejemplo completo sería:

```js
var array1 = [
  {"nombre": "paco", "edad": "21"}
];

// Array con 2 objetos
var array2 = [
  {"nombre": "matias", "edad": "25"},
  {"nombre": "juan", "edad": "31"},
];

array1 = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = [
  {"nombre": "paco", "edad": "21"}
 ];

var array2 = [
  {"nombre": "matias", "edad": "25"}
 ];

 const array3 = [...array1 , ...array2]
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tu respuesta es una mala copia de [esta otra](/a/141024)? Una respuesta con solo código tampoco es útil. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Hola @bladimirrojassepulveda bienvenido... No puedes responder solo colocando código, tu respuesta debe estar acompañada siempre de una explicación breve (o larga según sea el caso). Te recomiendo leer las normativas de este sitio y sobre todo este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer