# ¿Existen varias formas de concatenar varios Array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

> Se valorará cualquier respuesta que reciba esta pregunta. Si bien, es una pregunta autorespondida, se valorará mucho cada grano de arena que aporte cada persona sobre el tema.
>
> El objetivo de esta publicación es hacer una recopilación de todas las posibles formas de concatenar *arrays* usando **JavaScript.**

### Concatenar **array** de diversas maneras

Es decir, si tengo los siguientes vectores:

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
    numerosB = [4, 5, 6];
```

Podría concatenarlos así:

```js
const array = numerosA.concat( numerosB );
```

Dándome como resultado un nuevo `array` como veremos en la siguiente demostración:

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

const array = numerosA.concat(numerosB);
console.log(array);
```

Sin embargo, lo anterior es una copia. Entonces, la idea es poder elegir cuando hacerlo de una manera u otra que permita operar, al menos, sobre el primer `array`

Entonces, la pregunta es, ¿existen varias formas de concatenar los **Array** en **JavaScript**?

> **Importante:** no se trata de concatenar dos o más array en uno, sino, las diferentes formas de hacerlo.

---

> **Importante:** las siguientes publicaciones pueden parecerse a ésta, pero son diferentes, por ejemplo:
>
> 1. [Concatenar horizontalmente valores de Array multidimensional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372700/concatenar-horizontalmente-valores-de-array-multidimensional), es diferente de esta publicación porque su tema consiste en concatenar valores de un array multidimensional y no diversas formas de hacerlo.
> 2. [Fusionar dos Arrays de objetos en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140443/fusionar-dos-arrays-de-objetos-en-javascript), es diferente de esta publicación, ya que su tema consiste en fusión de dos `array` de objetos
>
> Por lo tanto, esta publicación trata sobre diversas maneras de concatenar `Arrays`

Comment: Hola @Marcos, la pregunta no se basa en unir dos o más vectores, sino, diferentes formas de hacerla. Voy a colocar esa aclaratoria en la pregunta

Comment: Hola David, desde mi punto de vista, _¿Como unir dos arrelgos?_ puede tener muchas respuestas correctas. al igual que esta. Si la idea era crear una pregunta/respuesta canónica, deberías considerar convertirla a wiki así todos podemos contribuir.

Comment: Ok. Creo que sería una buena idea. No encuentro la opción de Wiki, ¿cómo haría en ese caso?

Comment: @Marcos, logré que la respuesta fuese una Wiki. Pero, no sé como hacerlo con la pregunta.

Comment: No, la pregunta no se puede convertir a Wiki

Comment: Ah ok, Gracias @Marcos :)

Comment: Seria mejor que pusieras la solución en una respuesta, no dentro de la misma pregunta. Esa respuesta podra ser aceptada y la pregunta cerrada.

Comment: Hola @CandidMoe, voy a evaluar de qué forma podré mejorarla. Aunque el objetivo es recopilar varias soluciones. Es decir, no cómo se concatenan dos `arrays`, sino, diversas formas de hacerlo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Efectivamente sí y estas son algunas opciones

> **Importante:** tome en cuenta que las opciones que se presentarán pueden ser una menos eficiente que otras, pero la idea general es visualizar lo que puede hacerse con los vectores en JavaScript.

Si partimos de dos (02) o más vectores (`arrays`) de números:

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
    numerosB = [4, 5, 6];
```

Lo podemos concatenar a partir de las opciones disponibles más adelante en esta publicación

#### Operador de propagación o Spread Operator:

La idea de utilizar el operador de propagación (...) es **descomponer los vectores (`arrays`)** en sus elementos. Por lo tanto, nos permite concatenar los vectores de la siguiente manera:

**Ver demostración:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

const array = [...numerosA, ...numerosB];
console.log(array);
```

Devolviéndonos un **nuevo vector (una copia de vectores concatenados).**

#### Mediante `Array.prototype.concat()`:

Este método, probablemente el más conocido, tiene como finalidad concatenar varios vectores en uno nuevo:

**Bien sea que lo utilicemos así:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

const array = numerosA.concat(numerosB);
console.log(array);
```

**De esta otra forma:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

const array = [].concat(numerosA, numerosB);
console.log(array);
```

**O directamente así:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

const array = Array.prototype.concat(numerosA, numerosB);
console.log(array);
```

Ademas, de permitir pasar una cantidad variable de argumentos, es decir:

```js
const nuevoArray = Array.prototype.concat(valor1, valor2, ..., valorN);
```

#### Mediante el método `push()`:

Normalmente, una de las formas más habituales de incorporar nuevos elementos a un **vector** es mediante el método **push():**

```js
const array = [];
array.push("Algún valor");
```

Sin embargo, podemos utilizarlo en combinación con el **operador de propagación (...)** para concatenar. A diferencia de los ejemplos anteriores, opera sobre un vector (array) determinado de los vectores que formarán parte de la concatenación, dando la posibilidad de que la concatenación no resulte en un nuevo vector (*array*).

Casi siempre se utiliza el primer vector sobre el que se va a operar.

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

numerosA.push( ...numerosB );
console.log( numerosA )
```

Ten encuenta, que con el método **push()** puedes concatenar más de dos (02) vectores, al igual que con los ejemplos anteriores:

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
numerosB = [4, 5, 6],
numerosC = [7, 8, 9];

// Aquí se concatenan tres (03) vectores:
numerosA.push( ...numerosB, ...numerosC );
console.log( numerosA )
```

Esto es posible porque el método **push()** permite pasar una cantidad variable de argumentos, mientras que el operador de propagación permite descomponer los vectores en sus elementos.

Por lo tanto, si tenemos algo parecido a esto:

```js
array.push([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);
```

Al combinarlo con el operador de propagación (...):

```js
array.push(...[1, 2, 3], ...[4, 5, 6]);
```

Tendríamos un resultado similar a esto:

```js
array.push(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Resultando en esto:

```
console.log( array ) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

#### Mediante el método `apply()`

Que podría ser utilizado de esta forma:

```js
Array.prototype.push.apply( numerosA, numerosB );
console.log( numerosA );
```

Y actúa como si en el vector **numerosA** se estuviese haciendo un **push()**

```js
numerosA.push( ...numerosB );
```

A la vez, que descomponen en sus elementos los siguientes vectores que pasen como argumentos.

**Demostración:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

Array.prototype.push.apply(numerosA, numerosB);
console.log(numerosA);
```

O simplemente, reemplazando `Array.prototype` por `[]`:

**Demostración:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

[].push.apply( numerosA, numerosB );
console.log( numerosA );
```

#### También de una forma no tan común:

También, si queremos ser un poco más creativo podemos definir nuestra propia función de concatenación.

Aún así, se seguirá utilizando el operador de propagación para permitir una cantidad variable de argumentos en la función a la vez que descomponemos cada vector en elementos:

**Demostración:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

// Esta función es capaz de concatenar:
const concatenar = (...vectores) => {
  return [...vectores];
}

// Aquí vemos sus resultados:
const array = concatenar(...numerosA, ...numerosB);
console.log(array);
```

Si además, pasamos elementos, aparte de vectores, simplemente se agregarán:

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

// Esta función es capaz de concatenar:
const concatenar = (...vectores) => {
  return [...vectores];
}

// Concatenamos:
const array = concatenar(...numerosA, ...numerosB, "Elemento 1", {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "David E Luna M"
});

// Y lo mostramos en la consola el resultado de la concatenación:
console.log( array );
```

Hemos definido una función, cuya cantidad de argumentos son variables y de cualquier tipo. Sin embargo, para concatenar con ella los vectores debemos descomponerlos de forma similar que cuando se hace **push()**:

```js
const array = concatenar( elemento1, elemento2, ..., elementoN );
```

También podemos hacer que nuestra función concatene sin necesidad de descomponer los vectores que pasan como argumento ya que se encargará de hacerlo ella misma:

**Demostración:**

```js
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

const concatenar = (vector, ...vectores) => {
  let auxiliar = [];
  
  if ( vectores.length > 0 )
    // Recorre los argumentos que han pasado por la función:
    for ( let vector of vectores ) {
      if ( Array.isArray( vector ) ) {
        auxiliar.push( ...vector );
        continue;
      }
      
      auxiliar.push( vector );
    }
    
  vector.push( ...auxiliar );
  auxiliar = [];
};


// Concatenar dos (02) vectores:
concatenar( numerosA, numerosB );

// Y mostrar los resultados en la consola:
console.log(numerosA);
```

**Explicación:**

Nuestra función `concatenar(vector, ...vectores)` concatenará sobre `vector` los `...vectores`. Dentro de nuestra función tenemos un vector auxiliar. En ella, se van a incorporar los elementos de los otros vectores a concatenar.

Luego, mediante `for ( let vector of vectores ) {}` se recorrerán los argumentos de la función (cada argumento, puede ser un vector o cualquier cosa) y luego se evaluará si el argumento es un `Array` o no. De ser un array lo descompone, lo agrega al `Array` auxiliar y continúa. Si ese no es el caso, simplemente,lo incorpora directamente.

Una vez se haya completado el reccorrido de todos los argumentos se procede a descomponer el array `auxiliar` y se incorpora a `vector` y finalmente se vacía:

```js
// Se vacía
auxiluar = [];
```

Después de tener lista nuestra función podemos usarla como queramos para concatenar cualquier cosa en un `array`:

```js
...

concatenar( numerosA, numerosB, {
    id: 1,
    nombres: "David E Luna M"
} );


console.log( numerosA );
```

No solamente se puede utilizar para concatenar `Arrays` de cualquier tipo, también para agregar nuevos elementos al primer `array`:

```js
concatenar( numerosA, numerosB, 1, 3, 6, {
    id: 1,
    nombres: "David E Luna M"
}, "Una cadena" );

console.log( numeorsA );
```

Es decir, en esta última demostración:

```js
// Nuestros vectores de ejemplo:
const numerosA = [1, 2, 3],
  numerosB = [4, 5, 6];

// Nuestra función si queremos ser creativos:
const concatenar = ( vector, ...vectores ) => {
  let auxiliar = [];

  if ( vectores.length > 0 )
    // Recorre los argumentos que han pasado por la función:
    for ( let vector of vectores ) {
      if ( Array.isArray(vector) ) {
        auxiliar.push( ...vector );
        continue;
      }

      auxiliar.push( vector );
    }
  
  // Descomponemos «auxiliar» en sus elementos y
  // lo incorporamos a «vector»
  vector.push(...auxiliar);
  
  // Vaciamos nuestro vector auxiliar:
  auxiliar = [];
};

// Probamos nuestra función concatenar cualquier cosa
// en un array:
concatenar( numerosA, numerosB, 1, 3, 6, [12, 20], {
  id: 1,
  nombres: "David E Luna M"
}, "Una cadena");

// Y mostramos los resultados en la consola:
console.log( numerosA );
```

#### Referencias

Referencias para profundizar un poco:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)
- [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)
- [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply)

Answer (score 2):

También se puede combinar el `operador de propagación` con la recursividad.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6]

const arr3 = [{
  name: 'john',
  lastname: 'perez'
}]

const contactArrays = (total, ...arrays) => {
  if (arrays.length == 0) {
    return total
  }
  
  // va vaciando arrays y llenando total
  total.push(...arrays.shift())
  return contactArrays(total, ...arrays)
}

const result = contactArrays([], arr1, arr2, arr3)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Interesante respuesta @facu.

Comment: gracias @davi lo tuyo me motivo a seguir buscando soluciones y aprendiendo!!