# ¿Cómo concatenar varios arrays?

Tags: javascript

Estoy en un ejercicio simple, donde nos piden:

> Cree una función que concatene n arrays de entrada, donde n es variable

Por ejemplo

```
concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7])
concat([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Debería devolver

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Tengo la siguiente implementación, pero no funciona

```js
function concat(/**/) {
  const arrays = arguments;
    let arrayCollections = [];
    let result = [];
    for(let i = 0;i<arrays.length;i++) {
        result.push(arrays[i]);
    }
    result.forEach(el => {
        if (Array.isArray(el)) {
            result.concat(el);
        } else {
            result.push(el);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(concat([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]))
console.log(concat([4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))
```

Comment: @BetaM Gracias :D

Comment: @BetaM Sabiendo que es que un ejercicio y que Array ya tiene los métodos concat y flat, dudo que se acepte una solución que simplemente usa el API de Array. La función quedaría tan tonta como `let concat=(...arrays) => arrays.flat()`

Comment: Cierto es @Pablo debido a eso lo deje a nivel de comentario

Comment: Hola @anythingg, [quizás esto le pueda ayudar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422413/existen-varias-formas-de-concatenar-varios-array-en-javascript). Allí se explican varias formas de concatenar, con y sin métodos.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Muchas gracias, me ha ayudado mucho a dar con la solución

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si pudieses usar metodos de array podrías optar a:

```
const merge = (a, b) => a.concat(b);
```

Ó

```
const merge = (a, b) => [...a, ...b];
```

También:

```
const union = (...arr) => [...new Set(arr.flat())];
```

Comment: Buenas, si puedo usar métodos y es también válido, pues no es un ejercicio calificado (solo es uno de superación),  tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho